# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable: This shows up when I am trying to work with an excel file in Python using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

The error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" is popping up on line 11 when I try to run the following code. Using the debugger, I'm pretty sure the file from in the folder was pulled, so I don't think that is the issue.

```
import openpyxl
from math import cos
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')

sheet1 = wb.active

#assigning new column name
sheet1.insert_cols(3)
sheet1.cell(row = 1, column = 3).value('y2 = cos(x)')

# Calculating the cos() of the values in row 1
for row in range(2,sheet1.max_row + 1):
    sheet1.cell(row = row, column = 3).value = math.cos( sheet1.cell(row = row, column = 1) ) 
#-------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...excelPractice.py", line 11, in <module>
    sheet1.cell(row = 1, column = 3).value('y2 = cos(x)')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I'm new to learning Python and this is my first attempt with excel, so a good explanation on how to fix and understand this to avoid future problems would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to change `.value()` notation:

`sheet1.cell(row = 1, column = 3, value='y2 = cos(x)')`

You can use Worksheet.cell() like this example:

`d = ws.cell(row=4, column=2, value=10)`

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html